# How to enable USB debug trace level with windows kernel mode debug

Tags: windows, usb, windbg, kernel-module

I have set up kernel-mode debug in Windows 10.
And I have set `ed Kd_DEFAULT_Mask 8`.
In Windbg, it displays many infomation but not useful for me.
I'm debugging an USB xHCI host controller issue. So I want to print information deeply with USB.

In windows XP, I will do `ed USBPORT!USBPORT_Debug_Trace_Level 4` to display information from USBPORT.SYS level.
But in windows 10, when I try this command, it says

> Could't resolve error at USBPORT!USBPORT_Debug_Trace_Level 4.

I did this in Windows XP for a long time ago. And I can't remember if there is any other commands need for this.
Could someone tell me the correct way for this?

Answer (score 1):

The USB stack has moved to ETW tracing for all of its logging. Detailed information is available on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151577(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the relpy. I will try ETW tracing.